# Data.Set member lookup in parallel

Tags: haskell

I'm trying to do a parallel (multiple cores) lookup in Data.Set using `member` function as in the code below:

```
import           Control.Parallel.Strategies (parMap, rpar)
import qualified Data.Set as S

cntSeq :: S.Set Int -> [Int] -> Int
cntSeq set xs = foldl (\c x -> c + (mmbr set x)) 0 xs
  where
    mmbr st x | S.member x st = 1
              | otherwise = 0

cntPar :: Int -> S.Set Int -> [Int] -> Int
cntPar n set xs =
  let
    chnks = chunksOf n xs
    tr = transpose chnks
  in sum $ parMap rpar (cntSeq set) tr
```

but seems like `cntPar` is not actually benefiting from multiple cores.

If I replace Set with just a regular list lookup the speedup for the parallel version is significant.

Do I need to recompile Data.Set with something like `-threaded` option?

(BTW, I do realize that `intersection` would be an option it's just that I'm interested in parallelizing set lookups -- that's just a simplified version of a different problem.)

Comment: I see a speed up (1CPU=1s vs 2CPU=0.7s for the parallelizable section) https://gist.github.com/Lysxia/51bd5e25371366184c59cc8223b4f2dd How are you benchmarking?

Comment: Minor things to try: `foldl` is almost always bad, try `foldl'`. Further, `transpose` looks suspicious. You can convert a `Bool` to an `Int` with `fromEnum`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You do not need to recompile `Data.Set`.  It is sufficient to compile the final program with the `-threaded` flag and run it with `+RTS -N` or similar.

However, a big problem with your test case is that I believe the execution time is entirely dominated by the traversal of the `xs` list by `chunksOf` with the subsequent `transpose`.  You saw a difference with list lookups because they're so slow, but set lookups in any set of realistic size will be too fast for you to observe any benefits.

Also, as a side note, `parMap rpar` doesn't really make sense.  `parMap` already sparks the computations in parallel, so the `rpar` is redundant (and introduces some additional trivial overhead, since it probably re-sparks the computations).  Instead, use `parMap rseq`, which is a strategy to calculate the list elements in parallel (`parMap`) by evaluating each of them to WHNF (`rseq`).

To see some benefit, you can try something like the following.  This passes in lists of lists to define the chunks which avoids traversing (and probably even actually creating) the lists.  Compiled with `-O2 -threaded` and run with `+RTS -N` on my 16-core machine, it runs the serial and one-chunk parallel versions in about 90ms.  The parallel version with ten chunks runs substantially faster, in about 30ms, and the 100 chunk version runs in 20ms.

```
import           Criterion.Main
import           Data.List (transpose)
import           Data.List.Split (chunksOf)
import           Control.Parallel.Strategies (parMap, rseq)
import qualified Data.Set as S

cntSeq :: S.Set Int -> [Int] -> Int
cntSeq set xs = sum (map (mmbr set) xs)
  where
    mmbr st x | S.member x st = 1
              | otherwise = 0

cntPar :: S.Set Int -> [[Int]] -> Int
cntPar set = sum . parMap rseq (cntSeq set)

main = do
  let evens = S.fromList [0,2..200000000]
  defaultMain
    [ bench "serial"      $ whnf (cntSeq evens) [0..999999]
    , bench "parallel1"   $ whnf (cntPar evens) [[0..999999]]   -- one chunk
    , bench "parallel10"  $ whnf (cntPar evens) [[i..i+99999] | i <- [0,100000..900000]]  -- 10 chunks
    , bench "parallel100" $ whnf (cntPar evens) [[i..i+9999]  | i <- [0,10000..990000]]   -- 100 chunks
    ]
```

The benchmark output on my machine:

```
benchmarking serial
time                 90.63 ms   (90.21 ms .. 91.02 ms)
                     1.000 R²   (1.000 R² .. 1.000 R²)
mean                 92.47 ms   (91.81 ms .. 93.48 ms)
std dev              1.372 ms   (807.8 μs .. 2.023 ms)

benchmarking parallel1
time                 91.13 ms   (90.50 ms .. 91.77 ms)
                     1.000 R²   (1.000 R² .. 1.000 R²)
mean                 91.73 ms   (91.38 ms .. 92.26 ms)
std dev              696.0 μs   (427.3 μs .. 905.7 μs)

benchmarking parallel10
time                 31.25 ms   (23.77 ms .. 37.88 ms)
                     0.897 R²   (0.745 R² .. 0.987 R²)
mean                 54.53 ms   (43.81 ms .. 81.93 ms)
std dev              29.69 ms   (18.88 ms .. 40.02 ms)

benchmarking parallel100
time                 19.99 ms   (19.81 ms .. 20.19 ms)
                     1.000 R²   (1.000 R² .. 1.000 R²)
mean                 20.13 ms   (19.99 ms .. 20.62 ms)
std dev              536.7 μs   (111.9 μs .. 1.043 ms)
```

Comment: Thanks for the explanation -- I see I need to go differently about generating and traversing the list. Also the `rseq` comment was very helpful,